# How to optimize the following query Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.8

I have the code which is working perfectly fine.

```
 $amenityCategoryMapping1 = AmenityCategoryMapping::where('property_id', $property->id)
    ->orderBy('amenity_name','asc')
    ->orderBy('updated_at','desc')
    ->pluck('category_id', 'amenity_name')->toArray();

$amenityCategoryMapping2 = AmenityCategoryMapping::where('company_id', $property->company_id)
    ->orderBy('amenity_name','asc')
    ->orderBy('updated_at','desc')
    ->pluck('category_id', 'amenity_name')->toArray();

$amenityCategoryMapping3 = AmenityCategoryMapping::whereNull('property_id')
    ->orderBy('amenity_name','asc')
    ->orderBy('updated_at','desc')
    ->pluck('category_id', 'amenity_name')->toArray();

$amenityCategoryMapping = array_merge($amenityCategoryMapping3, $amenityCategoryMapping2, $amenityCategoryMapping1 );
```

However, currently I am executing 3 different query to extract data from the same table just using different parameters. Is there any way to minimize this query requests and still receiving the same results?

Currently, while plucking if two array has the same key then I am replacing `amenityCategoryMapping3` by `amenityCategoryMapping2` and that by `amenityCategoryMapping1`. That is more priority should be given to `amenityCategoryMapping1`

Comment: is the order in merged array important?

Comment: @user3532758 yes

Comment: You could perhaps use a `union`, remove`pluck` and `toArray` methods from 1 and 2, then use `union` on 2 to merge 1, then on 3 to merge 2. Use pluck on the final one. That should take care of the duplicates. But, do analyse performance before discarding your current approach. Union could be faster or slower depending on your dataset and your memory limitations.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `orWhere` function

---

```
$amenityCategoryMapping1 = AmenityCategoryMapping::where('property_id', $property->id)
    ->orWhere('company_id', $property->company_id)
    ->orWhereNull('property_id')
    ->orderBy('amenity_name','asc')
    ->orderBy('updated_at','desc')
    ->pluck('category_id', 'amenity_name')->toArray();
```

Comment: Sorry, it won't work because of the order of array merge. In this case, the key with latest updated_at value will replace all other data. However, clearly mentioned data came from property_id > company_id > null (property_id). This violate the array_merge concept on the question.

Comment: I think there is no need to merge the array since all the data come. Try to remove the toArray function and add the get function()